# Using a regular expression for FILTER with Pig Latin (or java in general)

Tags: java, regex, hadoop, filter, apache-pig

I am trying to parse through a single field in my dataset. I am trying to filter out all of the tuples with movies containing a bracket '{' anywhere in the title. When I run this I get a java error saying that what I have below is not a valid regular expression.

```
raw_actors = LOAD 'hdfs:/user/XXX' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage('\t') AS (name:chararray,movie_data:chararray,role:chararray);
movie_actors = FILTER raw_actors BY NOT(movie_data MATCHES '.*{.*');
```

When I take out the .* in the beginning of the expression, it runs, but nothing gets filtered out... Any suggestions for writing a regular expression that doesn't care what comes before or after a given character?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Java regular expressions, the `{` character marks the beginning of character classes denoted by name, e.g. `{Alpha}`.  With just Java, you would escape the opening brace character with a backslash character (which Java requires be escaped also): `\\{`.

According to [the Pig Latin Reference Manual](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.8.1/piglatin_ref2.html#Comparison+Operators), you should "Use the Java [format](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for regular expressions" for the "MATCHES" operator, which links to the Javadoc for `Pattern`, which describes regular expression syntax.

This means that you should be able to apply the escape directly in the "MATCHES" Pig Latin operator.

```
movie_actors = FILTER raw_actors BY NOT(movie_data MATCHES '.*\\{.*');
```